# Google Apps Sheets if statement not executing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on a Google Sheets Script for my work, and have hit a road block. The goal here is to identify a cell in the heading row with a specific title and return the column it resides in. (Ie: in the heading row find "Email" in column "C" and return the number "3").
So far I've been able to find that the if statement isn't running. I'm pretty new to this language so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function findEmail(){
  var searchString = "Email";
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var row = 1;
  var columnValues = sheet.getRange(row, 3, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); //1st is header row
  var EMCol = columnValues.findIndex(searchString); //Row Index - 2\
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    var j;
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E2').setValue('Hello');
    if(data[0][i] == EMCol){
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E3').setValue('World');
//      Logger.log((i+1))
//      j = i+1
//      return i+1;
    }
    return j;
  };
}
```

[This is what the sheet looks like after it has ran. As you can see nothing inside the if statement ran so there is no "World at E3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TXal.png)

Comment: `findIndex` -> `indexOf`. Google Apps Script is JS 1.6, with some later additions. Also note the positioning of your `return` statement within your `for` loop over `data` with index variable `i`, so `i` is never anything but 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code I get a TypeError, GAS doesn't have a `findIndex()` method. If you just want to find the column index then this function should do the job.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the `Hello` and `World` lines.

```
function findEmail() {
    var searchString = "Email";
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var columnIndex;

    for (var i = 0; i < data[0].length; i++) {
        if (data[0][i] == searchString) {
            columnIndex = i + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    Logger.log(columnIndex);
    return columnIndex;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly without any need for tweaking. The "Hello" and "World" lines were just to test where the system stopped working. If I didn't receive one or the other I would know that that portion was broken.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, the Logger.log() method is better for testing like that, far less complex that writing to the sheet etc.